# Cannot open Neo4j Webadmin

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j and I want to get the exact execution time for cypher queries , I looked up the internet and I found that I need to open the webadmin interface in neo4j . 
Doing `http://localhost:7474/webadmin/` and It is not opened showing the message

This localhost page can’t be found

```
No webpage was found for the web address: 
http://localhost:7474/webadmin/
```

I have uncommented int he Neo4j.conf file

```
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false 
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true 
dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473
```

But nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 1):

`webadmin` was deprecated in neo4j 2.3 and removed in 3.0. Most, if not all, of its capabilities (including seeing Cypher execution times) are available through the neo4j browser.